# Server Logs not showing with log4j2

Tags: log4j2

When I migrate from log4j to log4j2 Server Logs not showing.

Log4j2.xml exist in classpath.

here is my log4j2.xml file

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Configuration status="INFO" packages="com.vermeg.maskpolicy.customLog" monitorInterval="5">

    <Appenders>

        <RollingFile name="FILE" fileName="${soliam.fo.logdir}/log/server.log" append="true"
                     filePattern="${soliam.fo.logdir}/log/$${date:yyyy-MM}/server-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d %-5p %X{userName}@%X{remoteAddress} [%c] %m%n"/>
                <ThresholdFilter level="warn"  onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
            <CronTriggeringPolicy schedule="0 0 0 * * ?"/>
        </RollingFile>

        <Console name="CONSOLE" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <ThresholdFilter level="INFO"  onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p %X{userName}@%X{remoteAddress} [%c{1}] %m%n"/>
        </Console>

        <Rewrite name="rewrite">
            <LogInterceptor/>
            <AppenderRef ref="CONSOLE"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="FILE"/>
        </Rewrite>

    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>

        <Logger name="com.bsb.soliam.fo.aspectj.AspectJLogger" level="${log4j.level}">
            <AppenderRef ref="rewrite"/>
        </Logger>

        <Logger name="org.jgroups" level="WARN">
            <AppenderRef ref="rewrite"/>
        </Logger>


        <Logger name="org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain" level="ERROR">
            <AppenderRef ref="rewrite"/>
        </Logger>

        <Logger name="org.springframework.flex.servlet.MessageBrokerHandlerAdapter" level="WARN">
        </Logger>


        <Logger name="org.apache.commons.javaflow" level="INFO">
        </Logger>

        <Logger name="org.apache.commons.beanutils.locale" level="INFO">
        </Logger>


        <Logger name="com.bsb.soliam.fo.core.filepoller.JmsJobScheduler" additivity="false" level="${log4j.level}">
            <AppenderRef ref="rewrite"/>
        </Logger>

        <Root level="${log4j.root.level}">
            <AppenderRef ref="rewrite"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

log before migration
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k77d4.png)

log after migration just show hibernate log.
I don't know the main cause of this problem ,
can anyone help please